Page number of Table of Contents is linked to second page? I want first page?
The Table of Contents consists of 2 pages. The page number for this title has been referenced based on the second page of the Table of Contents, i.e., pages 9 and 10 in Roman numerals. However, in the list, the page number for this title appears as 10, but it should be corrected to 9.

Please always provide a full but minimal example that shows the problem. Then we know exactly what you are doing and can better provide help

There is proably a \addcontentsline after \tableofcentents, which would use the page at the end.  You need to move it before or inside \tableofcontents, which depends on the document class.  You could also use \section or \chapter instead of \section* or \chapter* inside \tableofcontents.
